# Is there any way to dispose of liquid fuel?

Tags: fuel, liquid-fuel-stoves

So that's the case - I have a camp stove and a bottle of liquid fuel for it (gas? benzine? petrol? ah, whatever). Hike is over and I have to get on a plane - thus I have to get rid of this fuel. How do I do it? Or maybe there's no way to do it right and I've got myself a problem?

Comment: The nicest option would be to try to give it to someone heading out whose first night is at the same place as your last.

Comment: Especially, do not call it "benzine" in an english speaking country when trying to get rid of it - "benzene" is not petrol in english, but what you would know as "benzol" (бензол). You might be facing strange questions about how the heck you even got hold of it, and why you are carrying it around.

Comment: Yeah, there's a nice discussion about it at http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/what-is-the-difference-between-gas-petrol-benzine-gasoline

Comment: A while ago I have created a community article here on TGO which tries to list all the different camping fuels with their respective names in various languages and geographies: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19151/how-are-camping-fuels-named-in-different-languages-and-geographies

Answer (score 12):

While writing the question, I've figured out an answer. I just **burn the fuel in the stove**.

Maybe this little knowledge would be helpful.

Comment: Nobody to give it away to? Shame to just burn it for the sake of getting rid of it..

Comment: You can do this, but it's wasteful.

Comment: It's wasteful, but so is nearly everything. Burning a small quantity of leftover fuel pales in comparison to flying - a 1500km flight will burn around [30 liters of fuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_aircraft), so burning half a liter of leftover fuel is only about 1.6% of the fuel he'll burn on his way home. Or is roughly equivalent to what a car will burn while driving 6km - so when he gets home, if he does a 6km walk or bike ride to run an errand  instead of driving there, he'll have "repaid" the waste.

Comment: it's be easier to just use it to start a campfire. We usually just burnt off our unused fuel in the fire. Fun stuff. Just don't burn down the forrest.

Comment: @Johnny A flight's fuel consumption : burning fuel in a stove is a bad analogy, regardless of the amount burned. One is a literal waste, the other is holding upwards of 300 passengers..

Comment: @insane sorry, I wasn't clear in my comment, the fuel burm number I gave was per passenger, not for the entire plane. It would be an efficient plane indeed that could fly 1500km on just 30 liters of fuel!

Comment: Burning the fuel produces carbon dioxide, a greenhouse gas, but if you can't get it disposed of properly then that's better than letting it evaporate to the atmosphere - hydrocarbons are a more potent pollutant than carbon dioxide - or worse, the liquid fuel getting into a watercourse or the sea where it would be highly toxic to aquatic life. Burn it!

Answer (score 10):

I was recently in Mexico and bought some unleaded gas at a gas station as stove fuel. I gave the unused fuel away to a taxi driver to put in his car.

I suspect the same thing would work fine with the fuels sold as "white gas" or "camp fuel." I've heard conflicting information about exactly how this stuff is formulated, and for all I know it depends on the manufacturer. But what everyone seems to agree on is that it's extremely similar  to unleaded gas. Given the similarity, if a car owner has 20 or 30 liters of gasoline in their tank, I don't think it will hurt anything to add a half liter of white gas.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an opinion on that over at mechanics.stackexchange.com. I'm not a car guy, so I can't weigh in on it.

Comment: White gas is simply unleaded gasoline without the usual automotive additives. So yes, just put it in your gas tank.

Comment: Here's an article from Climbing.com about using white fuel when you run out of gas in your car. http://www.climbing.com/news/running-out-of-gas/

Comment: White gas has an octane rating of 50 to 55, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman_fuel).  It's probably fine to add to the gasoline for most cars as long as the proportion is low.  I wouldn't want to do what those guys in the climbing.com article did, which was to put white gas in the tank after the car ran out of fuel, except in an emergency.

Answer (score 7):

**Here are a few methods**

- If you have a lawnmower or weed eater you can dilute your gas by about 5% to 10% with it and burn it off that way, even if the fuel is 'bad'.
- Additionally, many fire departments will accept all manner of fuel, good or bad, and use it for backburning areas preparing for the summer fire season.
- Some auto parts stores will accept fuel for disposal.  Almost all will accept old engine oil.  I suggest you call an auto parts store in your area as the acceptance of fuel is regional depending on what government services there are to pick up the fuel.  Oil is recycled and all auto stores accept to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: A lot of this answer is written as if the person was trying to dispose of the fuel back at home, but the question states that they need to dispose of it because they can't take it on a plane when they go home (a very common situation). If you were back at home with your fuel, you could just pour it back into the can you bought it in.

Comment: You can't stop by an auto parts store or a fire house on the way to the airport?  I'm not sure I agree with that.

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem? The guy at the airport will take it from you. Proper legal disposal is now *his* business.

There might be a kiosk for dropping items you forgot to leave at home,  before dealing with people.

Comment: I would be worried that you have to give away the bottle too. When I informed myself about transporting stoves with planes (internationally) the information I got was that theoretically nothing can smell of gasoline, otherwise it may be confiscated. That may not be enforced everywhere, but you need to be aware of that risk.

Comment: it maybe against the law to take flammable liquids in to the local airport, you may find "his job" is now to place you into jail.

Comment: Why would you want to keep the bottle it came in?  And if I understand the comment correctly then even if you dumped it or used it up then you could still not take it onnthe plane anyway.

Comment: @JDlugosz the contaminated bottle may be part of the stove (e.g. my MSR; the bottle could be filled from a car fuel can).

Comment: Right, so he couldn't take it on the plane even if emptied ahead of time.

Comment: @JDługosz the can could be emptied and aired ahead of time.  You would be at risk of losing the bottle because of a lingering smell if they opened it, but wouldn't be carrying a bottle of petrol.